# Does Ruby on Rails Encourage One to Violate YAGNI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm learning Ruby and Rails and I plan to write my first application using TDD via rspec. But right now I'm finding some friction between my principles and the way most of the Rails community seems to operate. Most of the examples and tutorials I see are telling me to generate my code. I can even generate scaffolding for my objects along with rspec specs in one command. Although that's really slick, it doesn't feel right. If I generate a bunch of properties and methods that I don't actually need right now, that's violating YAGNI, right?

Comment: Not a big fan of the given generators.  The only one I use regularly is `rails g migration`.  It's really a personal preference thing - But I tend to write what I need for the other ones, as I need them.

Answer (score 1):

Scaffolding can be a useful tool for fast prototyping but it's actually rarely used in production applications. Also, scaffolding a CRUD resource really isn't going to generate a lot of "extra stuff." But at the end of the day it's just a preference and fit thing. If you can generate a scaffold and modify it to fit your application, and that saves you time, go for it. But generally you'll find it's easier to just create the files yourself, once you learn the nuances of the framework a little more. But overall I don't really think scaffolding violates YAGNI too much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating a lot of stuff that you have to delete, maybe you are just using the wrong generator?

Note that you should use a scaffold to create a model that will have actions in the controller too. There are other generators, for example, if your Model should not have a respective controller at all, you want `generate model`, not `generate scaffold`, or if a table don't really needs a model at all you can use `generate migration`, or for a controller without models, `generate controller` and so on.

So assuming you are using a scaffold in the right place, that is, to create a model that needs a controller. Scaffold actually generates

- A migration with the attributes in your input (YGNI)
- Test files (YGNI)
- Controller entries for the crud operations (Maybe YAGNI; You can simple delete the methods you don't need for the file. Should be easier anyway than type the whole file yourself)
- Views for the actions it generates in controller (Again, delete the ones that you will not need)
- A CSS file (This is a must to delete or edit, always, if you plan to move to production)